# ASP.NET MVC 4 - using post method

Tags: c#, post, formatter

In Visual Studio 2010, I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for creating a web api project as in this sample : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9vBxAH4f5E

Things work fine - I succeed using `GET` method, but when using `POST` method, I encounter a problem:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

My `webapiconfig.cs` looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter f;

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        f = new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter();
        f.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        config.Formatters.Add(f);
        // application/x-www-form-urlencoded ???
    }
}
```

Why am I encounter a problem:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

The full error message:

> Message: "An error has occurred." ExceptionMessage: "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."
>   ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException" StackTrace: " at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger) at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger) at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider
>   metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(HttpParameterBinding
>   parameterBinder) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl(IEnumerator`1
>   enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

The request header:

> ```
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
> Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
> Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
> ```

The response header:

> Cache-Control: no-cache  Pragma: no-cache  Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8  Expires: -1  Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/8.0  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 18:06:10 GMT  Content-Length: 1111

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to add the new media type to the list of supported formats:

```
f = new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter();
f.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
f.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Comment: I did that - still have the same problem. See new extended details I put on my post on this thread. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. Long time ago ... There are some changes in code I had to do (don't remember - I can dig in code and put some code ...

Comment: Looking back on this now it feels like an IIS config issue.