# ASP.Net No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html

Tags: c#

I'm making an CRUD application with ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework), using Web API and MVC together. Everything seems fine until I tried to get the list of information from my Db. In specific, I got this error:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html

Down here is my Controller in MVC and the error come from the

> thonList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync>().Result

Here is my controller source code:

```
using LapBK_MVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LapBK_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class ThonController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Thon
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            IEnumerable<mvcBK_Thon> thonList;
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Thon").Result;
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            thonList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<mvcBK_Thon>>().Result;
            return View(thonList);
        }
    }
}
```

When I checked with Postman, the Content-Type is text/html, I don't know how to change it to application/json, tried many ways. If we got any ideas, I really appreciate that, thank you !

Comment: See this might helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729184/asp-net-mvc-4-using-post-method

Comment: Why dont you get the data as text/html into a list. Now convert this list to json and then return it.

Comment: @MohammedGadi Thanks for your suggestion, but It doesn't help me sir :(

Comment: @PraneetNadkar The first thing is how can I do that sir ? I'm a newbie with ASP.Net. The second one is. I prefer to make it become application/json, cause that the easiest way for me.